# Why won't this simple redirect script work?

Tags: php

I am trying to detect which platform the user is using with this script at the very top of my index.php page, however it doesn't redirect when visit the page on my computer browser (it should redirect to google.com)

```
<?php

//Detect special conditions devices
$iPod    = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
$iPhone  = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$iPad    = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
$Android = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$webOS   = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");

 //do something with this information
if( $iPod || $iPhone ){
header("Location: http://example.com/myOtherPage.php");
 }else if($iPad){
//browser reported as an iPad -- do something here
}else if($Android){
header("Location: http://example.com/myOtherPage.php");
}else if($webOS){
header("Location: http://google.com");
}

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: `var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);` - what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I would bet it's because that script isn't pulling your user agent. Add an `else` at the end of that conditional. Because it's not falling into any of the categories it's not being redirected

```
  <?php
       if( $iPod || $iPhone ){
           header("Location: http://example.com/myOtherPage.php");
       }else if($iPad){
           //browser reported as an iPad -- do something here
       }else if($Android){
           header("Location: http://example.com/myOtherPage.php");
       }else if($webOS){
           header("Location: http://google.com");
       }else{
          echo 'User agent not detected';
       }
```

Comment: Yes it's echoing not detected. Any suggestion on why / what I can do?

Comment: As Jon Stated, do `var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);' to see what your user agent is and add it to your conditional statement. What device/browser are you using? Also, if you are doing something important based on user agent please be aware that this can be spoofed.